# Spring Boot SSL webapp iOS testing

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-certificate, keytool

I'm experimenting with Spring Boot to create a WebApp.

In order to create a SSL certificate I issue the following command:

```
keytool -alias devssl -keystore devssl.p12 -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA256withRSA /
-keysize 2048 -storetype PKCS12 -validity 365 -dname "CN=Frankie, OU=Frankie O=Frankie, /
L=City, S=State, C=UK" -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,DNS:blueye,IP:127.0.0.1,IP:10.1.1.2"
```

Which from what I can understand means that such certificate will be valid for the following addresses:

- localhost
- blueye
- 127.0.0.1
- 10.1.1.2

The certificate is very easy to install on Spring:

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=devssl.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-alias=devssl
security.require-ssl=true
```

After I install the certificate under Trusted Root Certification Authorities in Windows it also works great.

**I just can't get it to work under iOS.**

I email myself the certificate.
Install it on the iPhone.
But I always get the "this connection is not private".

[image]

Any idea how to make this work on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was pushing on this trying to get iOS to accept a self-signed certificate as the single source of truth. I got to work around it by issuing a proper personal Certificate Authority. Making iOS trust that authority. And then signing the website with a certificate validated by that authority.

I will describe the needed commands as they may save someone a couple of hours. The following is a "birds eye" of what we'll do.

**AUTHORITY** - this will act as the source of trust for all certificates you sign. You will have to install the Authority on every single machine/phone you'll want with custom certificates

1. Generate a private key for a Certificate Authority (CA)
2. Generate a Certificate for the Certificate Authority (CA)
3. Install Certificate Authority on Windows
4. Install Certificate Authority on iOS

**CLIENT** - we can issue private keys for all our projects inside our network. Those private keys will be validated by our own generated and installed authority.

1. Generate a private key for the client
2. Generate a Certificate Sign Request (CSR)
3. Have CA sign the CSR thus generating the client Certificate
4. Merge the client certificate and the CA certificate into a pkcs12 file which is read by Spring

---

**Now for the actual commands:**

Generate a private key, we'll also use an identical command to generate one for the client:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out myCA.key 2048
```

Generate a certificate for your Certificate Authority. You'll be asked several questions, none of them really matter, they will only serve to identify your certificate to yourself.

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key myCA.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out myCA.pem
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key myCA.key -sha256 -days 1825 -out myCA.crt
```

You now have three files. The myCA.key (private key) and the myCA.pem and myCA.crt which are the certificate file for your certificate authority.

**Install on Windows:**
Click the `myCA.crt` file on Windows and follow screen instructions. Then click Start -> Run -> `` certmgr.msc`. It will open the Windows Certificate Manager. You will find the certificate you installed under "Intermediate Certification Authorities". You'll want to drag that file to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".

**Install on iOS:**
Email the `myCA.pem` file to yourself. Open the email on iOS using the Apple Mail App. Follow the instructions and certificate will be installed. To uninstall you can go to Settings -> General -> Profile. After proper installation iOS requires a second step for you to trust the certificate, you must go to Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings and Enable Full Trust For Root Certificate.

---

You now have a local CA (Certificate Authority) installed on both your Windows machine and your iOS phone. Lets create a website certificate.

---

Generate a private key for the website.

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out myWebsite.key 2048
```

Generate a CSR (Certificate Sign Request):

```
openssl req -new -key myWebSite.key -out myWebsite.csr
```

Now that we have the website key and the certificate sign request we need to **create a config file that openssl will use to generate our website certificate**. Create a file called `myWebsite.ext` with the following info. The only thing you must make sure is the alt names. You can have both IP's and DNS. Be sure to enter all the alternatives that your site will use.

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
DNS.2 = mywebsite
DNS.3 = mywebsite.local
IP.1 = 10.1.1.3
IP.2 = 127.0.0.1
```

Now we'll use the CA certificate and private key together with the CSR (Certificate Sign Request) and the config file to generate a proper certificate for the website. Since iOS 13 Apple only allows a max of 825 days on certificates so that's what we'll use.

```
openssl x509 -req -in myWebsite.csr -CA myCA.pem -CAkey myCA.key -CAcreateserial -out myWebsite.crt -days 825 -sha256 -extfile myWebsite.ext
```

You'll now have the following files:

```
myCA.key      - certificate authority private key  
myCA.pem      - certificate authority certificate pem format
myCA.crt      - certificate authority certificate crt format
myWebsite.key - website private key  
myWebsite.csr - website certificate sign request  
myWebsite.ext - website config file for openssl sign request  
myWebsite.crt - website certificate crt format
```

The only thing missing is to convert the myWebsite.crt to p12 format which we can do with the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in myCA.crt -inkey myCA.key -in myWebsite.crt -inkey myWebsite.key -name myWebsite -out myWebsite.p12
```

Now, to make Spring Boot use this certificate just open `application.properties` file and make sure it has these lines:

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
# The path to the keystore containing the certificate, place it src/main/resources
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:myWebsite.p12
# The password used to generate the certificate
server.ssl.key-store-password=PASSWORD-USED
# The alias mapped to the certificate (the -name myWebsite on the last command)
server.ssl.key-alias=myWebsite 
# force SSL 
security.require-ssl=true
```

And there you have it. A dev or internal project with proper SSL validation. Hope this saves someone some time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were having trouble creating the certificates correctly, for a great guide on how to do that, check out:

https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/introduction.html

If you follow it exactly, and know what your DNS name is, and what cipher you are using, you shouldn't have any problems. I provide my configuration files for making the certificates, along with a project that helps with sockets, below:

https://github.com/eamonwhiter73/IOSObjCWebSockets

Comment: Looks interesting. Congrats on the project. Regarding the SSL part, the accepted answer is still a more straightforward path. PS, SO frowns upon not sharing the relevant content on site so ideally you should edit, put here the relevant part and also keep the link.

Comment: in truth this is my first project where i am trying to contribute to the community a tool for people, its a little daunting, but naturally i am a little overeager to show it to people :)

Comment: :) Keep it up. Even if this doesn’t get much traction putting your work out there does wonders for your own growth as a developer.

Comment: thanks man that means a lot, I am mostly self taught but I have on the computer game for a while

Comment: i only decided to do it when i struck out with socketrocket and another one I can't remember which one, and then i just decided to do a deep dive and make one myself :) I think it may have been the certificates all along though lol